# How to execute Jenkins job parallely for Testcafe tests execution

Tags: testing, automated-tests, jenkins-pipeline, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have created the Jenkins job to execute the TestCafe tests, the job is working fine.
But I want to execute multiple jobs parallelly.

As TestCafe runs tests on the default port, it is not allowing me to execute jobs parallelly.

Can anyone please suggest how to achieve this?

I tried to execute the jobs parallelly, but its is giving an exception port already in use.

I am not able to change the port in Jenkins job

Answer (score 0):

When starting TestCafe, you can set ports:

https://testcafe.io/documentation/402644/reference/testcafe-api/testcafe/createrunner

https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#--ports-port1port2

Use different ports for each parallel task.